# How much knowledge does a module needs to have about the project

Tags: node.js, architecture, software-design

I am trying to make modules have less knowledge about my other modules it is using.
For example, my controller that manages user creation will take a database module and use it to create a user. It will first to parse the details in req, and then pass it to database module, calling a particular function.

```
registerController.postUser =  function(req, res, next){
    email = req.body.email;
    password = req.body.psw;
    var pswHash = crypto.createHmac('sha256',secret).update(password).digest('hex');
    db.register.createUser(email,pswHash);
}
```

In this case the controller module knows my db module has a .register.creatuser function. What if I want to change the organization of the database module I will have to come and modify this part of the code too. Do you think this is enough seperation or no? Should I individually pass in functions instead of the whole db module, for example make the above code take one more argument that is the createUser function and use that instead of doing db.register.createUser.

Comment: I would suggest you to create a module for each service you have, for instance register module, products module, orders module, instead of having those inside db module. DB module should be a dependency of those services, not a holder. There should be a hierarchy like: controller -> service -> database | encryption, usually below levels does not know about above levels. Remember a module groups functionalities.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you to create a module for each service you have, for instance register module, products module, orders module, instead of having those inside db module. Then implement database modules should be a dependency of those services, not a holder.

There should be a hierarchy like: controller -> service -> database models | encryption, usually below levels does not know about above levels. Remember a module groups functionalities.

Services will hold the logic behind every activity, and controller the redirection logic based on the service outcome.

Something like:

**controller/register.js**

```
var register = require('./service/register');

registerController.postUser =  function(req, res, next){
    email = req.body.email;
    password = req.body.psw; 
    try {
        register.createUser(email,pasword);
    } catch(e) {
       // Handle email and password validation error
       // Handle attempting to create a record for existent user
       // Others
       res.render('singup?error', { message: 'There was an error!' });
    }

    //successfull implementarion
    res.render('login', { message: 'User registered successfully! Please login'});
}
```

**service/register.js**

```
var crypto = require('...');
var User = require('...');

module.exports = {
    createUser: function(email, psw) {
        // Validating fields
        if(email == undefined || psw === undefined)
           throw new Error('Field not valid');
        //Validating existance
        if(User.findByEmail(email) == undefined) {
            // Encrypting password
            var pswHash = crypto.createHmac('sha256',secret).update(password).digest('hex');
            //Create the user object 
            var user = new User({
               email: email,
               encryptedPassword: pswHash
            });
            // Save object
            user.save().then(function(user) {
              console.log('User created successfully');
            });
        }
    }
}
```

**models/user.js**

Here you have your database implementation either on mongo or relational database.

Comment: When there is db.save, wouldn't the db also hold the save function and other functions, making it a holder again?

Comment: if I want to swap the db implementation or function, then wouldn't I have to change the code in every service module in your implementation?

Comment: Well, for my point of view service is used to coordinate activities related to user creation like: user fields validation, user object creation, password encryption and database persistence. Maybe instead of invoking the db to save, you just need to import your schema object(either from mongo or a relational database), then persist the object.